# How to replicate a function in R and get the last result?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function which makes some changes to a DataFrame. I want to repeat this function N times and get the final Dataframe. How can I Achieve this?

Currently my function is:

```
DF// Dataframe

fun <- function(){
   // For some rows only
   DF_processed <- t(apply(DF[rows, ], 1, sum))
   
   // Add to original DF
   DF[rows,] <- DF_processed
   
   return DF

}
```

I want to run this function 3 times and get the final DF. I have tried this:

```
lapply(seq_len(3), function(x) fun())
```

but I cant get the results to save in my original DF

Answer (score 0):

**Using loop**

First, instead of modifying an object in the global environment, it's better to pass the object into the function as an argument and have the function return the modified object. So, in general, you should use a function that looks like

```
fun <- function(x) {
  # do some processing on x - this will create a local copy of it...

  # now return the modified object (this should not change
  # the original object). Also note that 'return' is a function
  # (like everything in R), so you need to use parentheses.
  return(x)
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
# define x
x <- ...

for (i in seq_len(3)) {
  x <- fun(x)
}
```

Note, however, that this will change the object pointed to by x, as the `for` loop is running in the global environment.

**Using Reduce**

You can use the `Reduce` function (see `?Reduce`) to apply a list of functions - in this case all the functions in the list are the same function, but this is not required - to a 'start value'. This is actually a method for composing functions:

```
# The starting value
x <- 2
# This is the function we want to apply
fun <- function(x) x*x

# The following is equivalent to "fun_list <- list(fun, fun, fun)", but more flexible
fun_list <-rep(list(fun), 3 )

fun_call <- function(f, ...) f(...)

res <- Reduce(fun_call, fun_list, x, right = TRUE)
```

Now `res` is the final result.

This is equivalent to the simple form

```
res <- fun(fun(fun(x)))
```

which is another way to do that, but less flexible.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without loops?

Comment: I've added more ways to do that in my answer above.